# How to extend styled-components props and pass to children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am scratching my head to understand how to extend the styled components so I can pass a couple of props to its children while making typescript lint properly. This is what I have:

```
// ButtonBase.tsx

export const ButtonBase = styled.button`
  background: var(--primary);
  border: none;
`;

// IconButton.tsx

type Props = {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
};

export const IconButton = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props>(({
    iconName,
    ...props
}, ref) => (
    <ButtonBase
        {...props}
        ref={ref}
    >
        <Icon name={iconName}/>
    </ButtonBase>
));
```

But the problem with this is it doesn't allow styled-components props like `as`, `theme`, etc. I have tried the following setups to varying degrees of outcomes:

Started here, forwarding the props the usual way to no success.

```
type Props = {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
};

type IconButtonType = FC<StyledComponentProps<typeof ButtonBase, any, Props, any>>;

export const IconButton: IconButtonType = ({iconName, ...props}) => (...);
```

The `ref` was not available, so added that.

```
type IconButtonType = ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<StyledComponentProps<typeof ButtonBase, any, Props, any>> & RefAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>;
```

Used `StyledComponentProps` but for some reason, the TS doesn't trigger if I miss `iconName`.

```
type Props = StyledComponentProps<'button', any, {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
}, any>;
```

Tried separating the `iconName` out, and now TS validates `iconName` but doesn't suggest anything about button.

```
type Props = StyledComponentProps<'button', any, any, any> & {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
};
```

I tried using the button attributes but styled props are then unavailable.

```
type Props = HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
};
```

This is what I have right now, but it throws an error for `as` prop, `"a" is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes`

```
type StyledProps<C extends Element, A extends Element = C> = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<C> & {
    as?: A
}; // I copied this from styled-components.d.ts

type ButtonBaseProps = StyledProps<'button'>;

type Props = ButtonBaseProps & {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
};
```

The goal here is to make `IconButton` work just like a styled-component taking `as`, `theme`, `ref`, and `forwardedAs`, and at the same time make TS suggest and validate props on the consumer side.

I think I am missing the composition knowledge to do this. I tried searching the internet but I believe the terms of my search are off the point, I get different results about composition but none of them really explain how to keep the styled-components props while adding custom props for nested children. Maybe it is not meant to be composed? In my previous project, I exported a `Button` with an `icon` variant and let the consumer do the composition. This is new to me, so any direction would be greatly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Do you mean `<ButtonBase>` is a styled component? And your `IconButton` component is supposed to be a wrapper, so you want to be able to pass all the same props as to `<ButtonBase>` + `iconName`? If so, please can you include the code for `ButtonBase` to make the question clearer?

Comment: @ghybs yeah, ButtonBase is styled component. I updated it

Answer (score 1):

> Used `StyledComponentProps` but for some reason, the TS doesn't trigger if I miss `iconName`.

You were almost there: the 4th type argument `any` refers to [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b2e2ad0e37d8ff55ba3507e141c7861815a6e374/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L75-L76):

```
// The props that are made optional by .attrs
A extends keyof any,
```

...so if you pass `any` as type argument, you are basically saying that all props are optional, hence the absence of error if you do not provide `iconName`.

In your case, you do not use `.attrs` method, so there are no optional'ed props, hence you can use [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#the-never-type) type instead.

---

Then, as you already realized, we still need to add the [`as`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b2e2ad0e37d8ff55ba3507e141c7861815a6e374/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L95) polymorphic prop (actually, there is also `forwardedAs`), so we now have:

```
type Props = StyledComponentProps<'button', any, {
    iconName: IconProps['name']
}, never // `never` optional'ed attributes from .attrs
> & {
    // Add `as` and `forwardedAs` polymorphic props
    as?: string | React.ComponentType<any> | undefined;
    forwardedAs?: string | React.ComponentType<any> | undefined;
}

() => (<>
    <IconButton as={"button"} iconName="foo" />{/* Okay */}
    <IconButton />{/* Error: Property 'iconName' is missing in type '{}' but required in type... */}
    {/*~~~~~~~~*/}
    <IconButton iconName="foo" type="bar" />{/* Error: Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined'. */}
    {/*                        ~~~~*/}
</>);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL5wC+BUEIcARFKhkwNwBQokscAZxgBPADZIy2PAGUR4sgGEGkAHZIVMAAr0wAmnQbMhYiQFo0yiGo0DOXLiLBI42iLoAMcALy4ucf3DAFioAciggSABccACSwa66ANoA5CrhSMkAulzU3A7CTi46ej6yJoqW1lrFADzJAEYArjAwVsnYKCrCUn4BQVZhEdFxVgkCKWkRWTnYagBuSFBwAPTLcPOLcG4wwFYooskScCgtUMBNMEh6+PSMAHQnMFACXAB8cABkvgErawCCZDIxz0nSBhCgJHIEj+ekgomEIGgYAAFkE4GBir1-CgBAB+aJCM4qADmcAAPog2DA7kpwFZ1DAACoFJA1TrCd4UxoqMhIfDANRkbg-cGQ3lkGH4wRPAWkinIdDU2mqBnMpxsrqcuDc3n8wXcaj2AWXKD4dDOEYqMbfAKTKLSonEg1cXloUSkZzBISxYLRAAUGLcAmG8WKAEpvO8VI1RKI8kgAB58eBe+AAIWarRUaZxzh8xnkdwuWYABr16ugANbE+g66JzUh+0ymDGgUjCMPCuD1aC8qDRFT07gl+NJ6Apqzey0ZlpWbwEYikCh8moACUZAFkADIzrMAUXEEQ02DGrz9fpwWMCwUGSEwV7uj8DuhmcFY+AjXnefqvNV3VhzAQkCvH4cEfO5nwEQ0fh+d8vBwd9oICV4QICGpLXWdJ4P6UJ0loZYUJ+Gpln-bNcxQsNO3sP1P2-X9CJg-x0OCUjgXgphiysJhaBw28vCYQgICYFZXhwZYACo4AAeUrFBhDgcTliQxjmIAzM5wIsTJL3KB6H7Io3EWEQ4GSXj0mSQI9BAYABAEWVAhUOBHGcZIcGoCyLjfJAAEdGmAVggQFJyWRMzQgkrGoxmwJgYGRJAImEikmErJBhES5g0Fs9KUuECAqFI9dtz+U5zmaK4103Hd1JUA94oZLUmDMhLyWYHF0oExcoQlWxXmSO4FKU1CmOnarrwGLCOqE4KnH4isoGEzSJLgHS9OiNUXI40gmAsmz1ggeAcTs4k0nqcQnIgaaNs4lR2oERp6msmB2tYICnpanU+QFCQ+oG5S4GIiiuCAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it is not truly extending the props, we are adding what's missing to the Props... what it resulted in was a broken behaviour: `<IconButton as={"a"} iconName="foo" href="#"/>` throws error at `href` as it is neither part of the `button` nor `Props`

Comment: Yes the polymorphic part is actually way more complex, and would probably be worth a different answer, or rather, question.